# How can I run javascript in different pages using Jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

It seems that after transitioning to a new page, the javascript cannot be ran.  Since most decent client apps now involve lots and lots of JavaScript, was is the general preferred pattern for Jquery mobile and using javascript within each page?

Comment: all JavaScript should be in the root page. so if index.html is your home page put all the JavaScript in that page

Comment: phill, can't accept your answer as its in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all JavaScript should be in the root page. so if index.html is your home page put all the JavaScript in that page

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, how do I run a function in another page once its javascript is stored inside one of the included javascript files on the main index page?

Comment: use the live() events: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the pageshow event and run jquery code depending on when the page is shown:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $('div').live('pageshow', function () { 
        if(this.id=="months.html"){
            //Page specific to a page div with "months.html" id
            alert("The month.html page was just shown");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this is correct but not exactly what jaff is asking for.
if he place this code in other page it'll not run.
only script that is placed in index.html or the "first" html laoded will be executed.